# sql server express needs restarts for fast query execution

Tags: sql-server, batch-processing, database-performance

I had SQL Server Express 2012 on my old laptop and my SQL batch process used to complete in about 12 hours. Then I got a new better laptop, copied the database over but now the batch takes a lot longer, about 24-30 hours. I checked the indexes, constraints etc. They are exactly the same. The only difference is that on old laptop I had SQL Server 32- bit and new one has 64 bit.

I notice that it starts running faster than the old laptop but then slows down as the batch progresses. When I restart the SQL Server process, it again starts running fast but then slows down again. So the same query in exactly the same database condition is often taking a lot longer to complete depending on when I did the restart.

Is there any way I can fix this problem. If not, is there any way to automate the restarting of sql server so that the batch runs smoothly without manual intervention.

Comment: Well, you can certainly use a scheduled task to restart your service, just write a simple batch file (`net stop <your service> ...`).  But I think you'd be better off figuring out what's actually going on.

Comment: How many CPU cores where there in old and now in new one. Sometimes more cores degrade the performance. Try setting to low affinity of the process. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I run the batch in SQL Server Management Studio. To use the batch file, I guess I would need the Sqls also run through the batch file. Am I right ?

Comment: Thank you Adil. The previous laptop had 2 cores. The new one has 4. I will try to use low affinity and see if it helps the performance.

Comment: One way to find the exact issue between both the systems is by comparing the query plans of the SQL running in batch process. And another thing you can try is by rebuilding all the indexes and updating the statistics can help your batch to run faster on your new system.

Comment: Thank you Rao Y. I can't check out the previous laptop now since it has got totally junked. I have done the index and stats but no luck. I think problem is not with the queries or database since when I restart the SQL Server process, it starts working fine but then slows down with time. The sqlservr.exe takes about 80 MB memory after restart but it starts taking up 1.5 GB of memory after some time. I understand SQL Server may need all that data when a query is running but the problem might be that it is clearing it when next query starts. So it is effectively working with very less RAM.

Comment: Nopes. No luck. Tried it with setting affinity to two processors but it is taking same time. Should I uninstall 64-bit version and install 32-bit version. Can that have an impact to perfromance.